# Identifying and removing a predefined pattern in a String (Java)

Tags: java, string

I have an input string that looks like

> abcd test{101010} efgh test{11111} ijkl test{0000}

I want to get rid of test{....} from the it and print

> abcdefghijkl

What are the different ways to scan through the String, Identify test{ and its consecutive } and get rid that snippet from the String? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "abcd test{101010} efgh test{11111} ijkl test{0000}".replaceAll("\\s*test\\{\\d+\\}\\s*", "")
```

use `replaceAll` with regex can do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry I could have put it up in a detailed manner. I can have any thing in between the {} (curly braces) not only digits Example: alphabets special characters etc. So how should my regex look like?

Comment: "abcd test{101010} efgh test{11111} ijkl test{0000}".replaceAll("\\s*test\\{\\w+\\}\\s*", "") is the updated regex. Thank You Chengpohi.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to replace the string with `""`

```
[test{[0-1]*}]*
```